# #error directive in C. How to display some #define

Tags: c, debugging

I need to display some relevant information in #error preprocessor directive.
For example:

```
#define myConstant 5

#if myConstant > 10
    #error myConstant has to be > 10, now %d  //should display "5"
#endif
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `#error` was introduced back in C89. Have you considered using C11's `_Static_assert` instead? While it doesn't solve your immediate problem, it's more flexible overall.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. `#error` doesn't allow/support that.

Instead, use `_Static_assert`, from C11:

```
#define myConstant 5

#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
_Static_assert(myConstant > 10, "myConstant has to be > 10, now " STRINGIFY(myConstant));
```

Output:

> ```
> test.c:5:1: error: static assertion failed: "myConstant has to be > 10, now 5"
>  _Static_assert(myConstant > 10, "myConstant has to be > 10, now " STRINGIFY(myConstant));
>  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```